# Could someone explain why my code is giving me the following error in safari?

Tags: html, css, xml, embed, external

I have recently been building an overlay system for a display in my lobby. I am using the embed tag as follows:

```
    <embed src="flatly.theme/index.html" style="width:237px;height:344px;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:1;position:absolute;">
```

this is the error I have been getting:

```
    [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/CAXX0504.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  (index.html, line 0)
```

If someone could explain to me why this is happening and how I can make it run fluently again, it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.html file you a trying to use in <iframe> not supposed to be there.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is part of [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

> is a mechanism that allows restricted resources (e.g. fonts,
>   JavaScript, etc.) on a web page to be requested from another domain
>   outside the domain from which the resource originated.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

And your domain is not allowed by xml.weather.yahoo.com

I believe this can sometimes happen for local html pages (file:///* )
And can be working as intended on any http server, even on http://localhost

it is explained in a lot of similar questions. 
[JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest, Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640909/3186447)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is detected cross domain request inside your "index.html" and block him