# facing a CORS error

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm facing a CORS error when I'm trying to download video from different domain. I tried a lot to solve it but couldn't.
Below is my js code.

```js
getVideoFile = function () {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
   blob;
   xhr.open("GET",myVideo, true);
   xhr.responseType = "blob";
   xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
   if (xhr.status === 200) {
    blob = xhr.response;
    putVideoInDb(blob);
    window.alert("Video file downloaded");
   }
   else {
    window.alert("Unable to download video");
   }
   }, false);
   xhr.send();
  };

  putVideoInDb = function (blob) {
   var transaction = db.transaction(["Videos"], "readwrite");
   var store = transaction.objectStore("Videos");
   var vid = {
     videoName:videoName,
     video:blob,
    }
   var request = store.add(vid);
   request.onerror = function(e) {
     console.log("Error",e.target.error.name);
    }
   request.onsuccess = function(e) {
     console.log("Done!!");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
```

Set this header value before sending your request. For more information you can read here [JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest, Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640561/javascript-xmlhttprequest-access-control-allow-origin-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [CORS error on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)

Of course this is a scenario where the domain is the same, but however the logic's the same...

There's a lot of articles out there about this topic.

Comment: I want to do it using only javascript and not AJAX jquery. It would be very helpful if you could provide the solution using javascript.