# CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, cors

I'm hosting a website that has a number of different domain names  pointing at it.

lets call the hosted website example.com and the url-forwarded domain names - example-x.com, example-y.com, example-z.com

When the url-forwarded domains are visited, cross domain requests are made back to the host site, example.com.

I'm currently making ajax GET requests to json files and receiving the following error;

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example-x.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Even though the preflight OPTIONS return a status of 200 and the GET method returns a status of 200.

**OPTIONS;**

[image]

**GET**
[image]

I have set the following CORs headers on the host htaccess;

```
# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https?://(www\.)?(example-x\.com|example-y\.com|example-z\.com)(:\d+)?$" ACAO=$0
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
# </IfModule>
```

And i'm call GET using the following ajax request;

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) { 
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined") { 
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else { 
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}; 

var url = 'http://example.com/data.json'; 
var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript');  
xhr.onload = function() { console.log('success');}; 
xhr.onerror = function() { console.log('error'); }; 
xhr.send();
```

***EDIT***

Removing `setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")` from  the ajax request has removed the preflight requirement, however the CORs error still persists, the screenshot below shows the request / response of GET, its my guess that the correct htaccess headers have not been set on the RequestURL - http://example.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/preloader_data.json

**GET - WITHOUT OPTIONS PREFLIGHT** 
[image]

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");` — This is nonsense. You are making a GET request. There is no content to specify the content-type of. This is also why you have a preflight OPTIONS request in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640561/javascript-xmlhttprequest-access-control-allow-origin-errors

Comment: @MartinChaov — Not a duplicate of that. The OP isn't trying to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header. They already have server side code which should set it as a response header. The question is why said code isn't working.

Comment: As Quentin says a GET request should not need to generate an OPTIONS request. Your client setup is likely wrong in the way mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, thanks for your reply.. its helped narrow down the issue. I've editted my question with the GET request/response i'm receiving now the preflight requirement is removed, i think the issue is htaccess / Header related

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve a json by a `GET` request. This should be a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests), and it does not need to have a preflight request.

If you look at the requirements for a preflight request from MDN, you can see that setting `Content-Type` other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` will cause this preflighted request.

If you look at the `content-type` from [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5), it is a **"SHOULD"** for *"a message containing a payload body"*. But your get request does not have a payload. As a result remove that header from your ajax call.

Comment: Hi ykaragol, thank you for your insight. i've edited my question with the GET request/response i'm receiving now the preflight requirement is removed. Im stiill getting the same CORs error... I think the issue might be related to a lack of header infomation set on json from htaccess..

Comment: To retrieve a json from cross origin via a GET request, you normally dont need to setup the cors headers. Can you try `xhr.responseType = 'json';` just before `xhr.send();`?

Comment: @Cam did you try it?

Comment: hey @ykaragol - unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: Getting the same error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example-x.com' is therefore not allowed access. No i don't need credentials, i've actually removed Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true from my htaccess

Comment: can you check your `htaccess` file? maybe a typo? Or you can try `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'` to see whether it is working or not?