# XHR status undefined

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I try to send a XHR request to a REST API but I can't get an answer.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a083d8e2f0000c61ee61140", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);

    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
  console.log("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
  console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
</script>
```

When I execut it, `xhr.status` remains undefined and it never enter in the `if (xhr.status === 200)`. I don't know why. Can someone help me?

**Edit:**

I fixed the JSON but I still have an error:

[image: Google Chrome console showing an error.]

The error is about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

> Failed to load http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a083d8e2f0000c61ee61140: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

So, I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640909/6113711) that says I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` in the HTTP header on [mocky.io](http://www.mocky.io/). I do it but it changes nothing:

[image]

Here is the new [mocky.io](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a083d8e2f0000c61ee61140) URL:

```
http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a083d8e2f0000c61ee61140
```

Does anyone see where my mistake is?

Comment: Well what is the readyState? You do not get status until it is 4

Comment: I ran that js code in my chrome console and it does enter the `if (xhr.status === 200)`

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/79Lcvv1k/ - which is your code with some output added - so ... problem was with the server side code, which you have since fixed

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't noticed the error in the `JSON`.
Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't noticed [the missing comma in the JSON](https://www.mocky.io/v2/5a038d6d3100000419916a9f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` is ignored when we access to the HTML file locally (from `file:///C:/.../index.html`).

To make it work, we have to mount a local server (For example, with [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)) and access to the HTML file through HTTP (`http://127.0.0.1:8887/index.html`).

Or use [this other Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) that automatically add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` in the header of the HTTP response.