# Getting CORS error while calling Dynamics 365 Operations JSON-Based custom service using Javascript

Tags: office365, axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am developing a simple SPA application and trying to access a Dynamics 365 for Operations JSON-Based custom service. I am using ADAL.js library for authentication. The way for authentication I am following from [This](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2016/01/31/crm-web-api-and-cors-support) Dynamics Community thread.

But opportunity, after successfully getting the valid token, and calling my target api with acquired token, I am unable to call the API and getting **[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** error.

**PSB screenshot for the same**

[image]

**Below is my code sample:**

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
   req.open("POST", organizationURI + "/api/services/ServiceGroup/Service/Operaton", true);

   //Set Bearer token
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
   req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

   req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
     req.onreadystatechange = null;
     if (this.status == 200) {
      var empData = JSON.parse(this.response).value;
      console.log(empData);
     }
     else {
      var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
      console.log(error.message);
      errorMessage.textContent = error.message;
     }
    }
   };
   req.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error, because your localhost conflicts with service domain. CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue.

Probably you have to add this snippet:

```
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Still if conflict comes between your hosted SPA & Dynamics API, have to solve it.

[JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest, Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21640561/7920473)

Comment: But, i think but not sure CORS by default enables in Dynamics 365? if it doesn't enable by default then what is the way to enable it?